# How to hide password in logging

Tags: c#, string

I'm printing command line arguments this way:

```
static void LogParameters(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Command line parameters: {0}", string.Join(" ", args);
}
```

Which will print `-username=Scott -password=cafebabe -nofail`. But I would like to print it as:

```
-username=Scott -password=******* -nofail
```

How do I make that anything appears after `password=` for this argument is printed with asterisks?

Comment: Taking a password via the command line (without the user typing it in) isn't safe. It might not show up in your program's log, but it's going to show up memory, and it is also going to show up in logs of the script that calls your application. This might or might not be a problem for you, but I thought I'd mention it since you're trying to make your app more secure.

Comment: It's for Windows service setup. Just like we can setup a service with username and password (using `services.msc`), this application would setup a service. Can't reveal more.

Comment: No worries on the non-disclosure stuff, I won't pry. It still may be worth thinking about prompting the user for the password w/ standard system calls if your app can do so (in an interactive mode), and warning users when they try to pass in a password in an unattended mode. If you can get them to run your program w/ the user token you need, you might also be able to avoid handling the password yourself. It's been some years since I've jumped through window's hoops, especially services and setup programs, so you're going to be better equipped to solve that riddle than I am :)

Comment: Thanks for your positive and criticizing comment! But I don't control this. This has to install in non-interactive mode with a batch script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two obvious ways to do this:

1. Iterate through your args array, find password argument manually and mask password
2. Combine arguments into a string and replace password using regular expressions

I would prefer the first one, using LINQ:

```
var argsForLogging = args
    .Select(arg => arg.StartsWith("-password=") ? "-password=(entered)" : arg);

Console.WriteLine("Command line parameters: {0}", string.Join(" ", argsForLogging));
```

It may look not that good, but it is easily readable, and there are no regular expressions :)

P.S. It is possible to make the code output not `(entered)`, but as many asterisks as there are letters in a password. However, it would still disclose very sensitive information.

**Update:**
If arguments format is not strict, then you need to take this into account.
For example, if it should be case-insensitive, then you may want to use this approach:

```
var argsForLogging = args
    .Select(arg => arg.Trim().StartsWith("-password=", true, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
        ? "-password=(entered)" 
        : arg);

Console.WriteLine("Command line parameters: {0}", string.Join(" ", argsForLogging));
```

Comment: Excellent one. Can I perform `StartsWith` case-insensitively ?

Comment: Thanks. I guess `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` would work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Normally

```
String maskString = String.Empty;
    String replaceString = "-password=";
    foreach (var item in args)
    {
        if (item.IndexOf(replaceString) >= 0)
        {
            maskString += replaceString + "********* ";
        }
        else
        {
            maskString += item+" ";
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Command line parameters: {0}", maskString.TrimEnd());
```

Or LinQ

```
var argsForLogging = args
 .Select(arg => arg.StartsWith("-password=") ? "-password=*********" : arg);

 Console.WriteLine("Command line parameters: {0}", string.Join(" ", argsForLogging));
```

Comment: Why to have `replaceString`? Why can't I have `-password=*******` ?

Comment: replaceString is token name.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void LogParameters(string[] args)
{
    string msg = string.Empty;
    foreach(var item in args)
    {
        var subParts = item.Split(new[] { '=' },  
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (subParts[0] != "-password")
            msg += item + " ";
        else
            msg += subParts[0] + "****** ";
    }
   Console.WriteLine("Command line parameters: {0}",msg.TrimEnd());
}
```