# Replace a part of string containing Password

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace

Slightly similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37700711/264325), I want to replace `argv` contents:

```
string argv = "-help=none\n-URL=(default)\n-password=look\n-uname=Khanna\n-p=100";
```

to this:

```
"-help=none\n-URL=(default)\n-password=********\n-uname=Khanna\n-p=100"
```

I have tried very basic string find and search operations (using `IndexOf`, `SubString` etc.). I am looking for more elegant solution so as to **replace** this part of string:

`-password=AnyPassword`

to:

```
-password=*******
```

And  keep other part of string intact. I am looking if `String.Replace` or `Regex` replace may help.

What I've tried (not much of error-checks):

```
var pwd_index = argv.IndexOf("--password=");

string converted;

if (pwd_index >= 0)
{
     var leftPart = argv.Substring(0, pwd_index);
     var pwdStr = argv.Substring(pwd_index);
     var rightPart = pwdStr.Substring(pwdStr.IndexOf("\n") + 1);

     converted = leftPart + "--password=********\n" + rightPart;
}
else
     converted = argv;

Console.WriteLine(converted);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solution

Similar to [Rubens Farias' solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37725213/1025555) but a little bit more elegant:

```
string argv = "-help=none\n-URL=(default)\n-password=\n-uname=Khanna\n-p=100";
string result = Regex.Replace(argv, @"(password=)[^\n]*", "$1********");
```

It matches `password=` literally, stores it in capture group `$1` and the keeps matching until a `\n` is reached.

This yields a constant number of `*`'s, though. But telling how much characters a password has, might already convey too much information to hackers, anyway.

Working example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xOFCyG

### Regular expression breakdown

```
(              // Store the following match in capture group $1.
  password=    // Match "password=" literally.
)    
[              // Match one from a set of characters.
  ^            // Negate a set of characters (i.e., match anything not
               //   contained in the following set).
    \n         // The character set: consists only of the new line character.
]
*              // Match the previously matched character 0 to n times.
```

Comment: Elegant and readable solution. And thanks for parameter-breakdown! :)

Comment: Add _RegexOptions.IgnoreCase_ to make it case-insensitive.  `Regex.Replace(argv, @"(Password=)[^\n]*", "$1********", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Answer (score 3):

This code replaces the password value by several `"*"` characters:

```
string argv = "-help=none\n-URL=(default)\n-password=look\n-uname=Khanna\n-p=100";
string result = Regex.Replace(argv, @"(password=)([\s\S]*?\n)",
    match => match.Groups[1].Value + new String('*', match.Groups[2].Value.Length - 1) + "\n");
```

You can also remove the `new String()` part and replace it by a string constant

Comment: Seems that it also cuts \n from \n-uname=K

Comment: This would work for me. But it is adding one more extra `*`. For `look`, it is creating `*****`